# ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs; When using solve_ivp in the scipy library

Tags: python, ode, scipy, numerical-modelling, differential-equations

I am solving an initial value problem using solve_ivp. The problem consists of computing the concentration profile of a set of reactions over time, given the initial concentrations and some of the reaction rate parameters. Furthermore, I have some experimental data of those concentration profiles at different temperatures for which I have to determine those reaction rate constants by optimizing those parameters. Here is my code implementation:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

Npoints = 1001
t = np.linspace(0, 1e-6, Npoints)
IC = np.array([0, 0, 0.5, 1.5, 0]) # initial conditions
species = ['Br', 'H', 'Br2', 'H2', 'HBr']
temperature = [1300, 1400, 1500]
exp_data1300 = pd.read_excel("File", sheet_name="1300K", usecols=[1,2,3,4,5])
exp_data1400 = pd.read_excel("File", sheet_name="1400K", usecols=[1,2,3,4,5])
exp_data1500 = pd.read_excel("File", sheet_name="1500K", usecols=[1,2,3,4,5])
exp_time = pd.read_excel("File", sheet_name="1300K", usecols=[0])
exp_data1300 = exp_data1300.to_numpy()
exp_data1400 = exp_data1400.to_numpy()
exp_data1500 = exp_data1500.to_numpy()
exp_time = exp_time.to_numpy()

def chain_HBr(t, conc, T, params): 
    # Exctract concentration data and parameters 
    cbr, ch, cbr2, ch2, chbr = conc
    Ea1, A1, m1, Ea2, A2, m2 = params
    R = 8.314 # Gas constant
    A3=5.41e9
    m3=2.05
    Ea3=7550
    A4=5.01e9
    m4=1.05
    Ea4=-680
    A5=5.06e8
    m5=0.1
    Ea5=-8400
    # Define reaction rate constants
    k1 = A1*(T/298)**m1*np.exp(-Ea1/R/T)
    k2 = A2*(T/298)**m2*np.exp(-Ea2/R/T)
    k3 = A3*(T/298)**m3*np.exp(-Ea3/R/T)
    k4 = A4*(T/298)**m4*np.exp(-Ea4/R/T)
    k5 = A5*(T/298)**m5*np.exp(-Ea5/R/T)
    # Define reaction rates of each reaction
    r1 = k1*cbr2
    r2 = k2*cbr*ch2
    r3 = k3*ch*cbr2
    r4 = k4*ch*chbr
    r5 = k5*cbr**2
    # Define species reaction rate
    dBrdt = 2*r1-r2+r3+r4-2*r5
    dHdt = r2-r3-r4
    dBr2dt = -r1-r3+r5
    dH2dt = -r2+r4
    dHBrdt = r2+r3-r4
    return np.array([dBrdt, dHdt, dBr2dt, dH2dt, dHBrdt])

def errorfunc(params, t, c_exp1300, c_exp1400, c_exp1500, y0):
    # Solve concentration profile at each temperature
    sol1300 = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(chain_HBr,[t[0],t[-1]],y0,t_eval=t,args=(1300,params),method='Radau',max_step=0.01)
    sol1400 = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(chain_HBr,[t[0],t[-1]],y0,t_eval=t,args=(1400,params),method='Radau',max_step=0.01)
    sol1500 = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(chain_HBr,[t[0],t[-1]],y0,t_eval=t,args=(1500,params),method='Radau',max_step=0.01)
    # Compute Residual sum of squares
    error1300 = np.sum((sol1300.y.transpose()-c_exp1300)**2)
    error1400 = np.sum((sol1400.y.transpose()-c_exp1400)**2)
    error1500 = np.sum((sol1500.y.transpose()-c_exp1500)**2)
    residual = error1300+error1400+error1500
    return residual

guess = np.array([-2e5, 4e12, -0.5, -7e4, 5e10, 0.5])
params_fit = scipy.optimize.least_squares(errorfunc,guess,args=(exp_time.reshape((len(exp_time))),exp_data1300,exp_data1400,exp_data1500,IC), max_nfev=10000)
```

But most solvers simply return: `ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs` because the time scale is of the order of 10^(-7), which gives a massive differential term in each iteration of solve_ivp. I have tried different solvers like LSODA, but that one just keeps computing an answer forever, and I have also tried setting a smaller max_step, but a max_step of 0.00001 still gives the same error, and anything smaller than that will take ages to solve on my computer. So, does anyone have any other tips in how to go about implementing this? Or what modifications could I make to give me a result?

Thanks!

Comment: NaN problems are generally quite easy to debug: You just need to find out where they originate. Have you checked that your user function `chain_HBr` never returns any NaNs? And if it does, why does it do so?